# How can I get selected records from ExtJS grid that uses a checkboxmodel

Tags: javascript, extjs

Given that I've got a ExtJS grid using a [CheckBoxModel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel), what is the best way to get a list of all the records where the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 26):

In ExtJS 4, to select records in a grid with selection model as Ext.selection.CheckboxModel do:

```
var selectedRecords = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
// And then you can iterate over the selected items, e.g.: 
selected = [];
Ext.each(selectedRecords, function (item) {
  selected.push(item.data.someField);
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: You can also do the following to save a few lines:
    Ext.pluck(grid_selection, 'data')

Comment: @postrational FWIW, Ext.pluck is deprecated http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-pluck (as of 4.0.0, use Ext.Array.pluck instead).

Answer (score 4):

simply by using `getSelection()` like this :

```
var selectedRecordsArray = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var arrayList=[],
 selected=Ext.getCmp('wpDetaPrdsDetailGrid').getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    Ext.each(selected, function (item) {
                       arrayList.push(item.data);                    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [grid checkbox question](http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-113171.html) is addressed on the the Sencha Ext JS 3.x Community Forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
var SelectedCheckbox=grid.getSelectionModel();
for(i=0;i<SelectedCheckbox.selections.length;i++){
    console.log(SelectedCheckbox.selections.items[i].data.field_name);
}
```